# How to scale the x-axis and y-axis non linearly, as per convenience?

Tags: plotting, graphics

[image]

Check the x and y axis. I want a command in which I can create such a plot.

Comment: Have a look at [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html).

Comment: @Jason B Resolved. Thanks.

Comment: `LogLogPlot[{x,x/2,x/3},{x,.01,1},PlotRange->{{.01,1},{2*10^-5,1}},PlotStyle->{{Red,Dashed},Orange,{Green,Dashed}},AxesLabel->{\[Theta],\[Delta]\[Theta]CRB}]`